# I can't see my update profile image using laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

i am trying to update the image of profil ,because to user at the beginning it creates account without image, after it goes the update, so i store the image in root `/aswakfolder/public/storage/profiles` and i insert image link in db `profiles/nameimage.jpeg`, i created a function in `helpers.php` file to display the image its work very will, the problem here is that I do not understand the helpers function, and it does not meet my needs, my need is when image upload and exists it displays my image if not it displays image not-found.jpeg,in my case it always displays not-found.jpeg.
stock image in my folder, and url image insert in db very well.

**UsersController.php**

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user=User::find($id);
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
       {
        $image = $request->file('image'); 
        $path = $request->image->store('profiles');
        $user->image = $path;
        }
        $request->image = $user->image;
        $user->id       = Auth::user()->id;
        $user->update([
            $user->name      => $request->name,
            $user->email     => $request->email,
            $user->telephone => $request->telephone,
            $user->daten     => $request->daten,
            $user->country_id=> $request->country_id,
            $user->state_id  => $request->state_id,
            $user->city_id   => $request->city_id,
            $user->image     => $request->image,

        ]);
        session()->flash('success', 'user updated successfully !!');
       return redirect('users'); 
    }
```

**helpers.php**

```
function productImage($path)
{
    return $path && file_exists('/aswakfolder/public/storage/'.$path) ? asset('/aswakfolder/public/storage/'.$path) : asset('/aswakfolder/public/storage/not-found.jpg');
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="inner" style="background-image: url({{ asset(productImage($users->image)) }})">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run the commend `php artisan storage:link` to create the shortcurt on `public/` folder.

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: thx for u answer i try ,i delete my storage folder and i try again but not work